# Trigger for Boolean Update (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am creating a sports database and am trying to add a trigger to my DDL. The aim of the trigger is to insert values into a table (commitment) whenever another table (player) has a college commitment (col_commit) change from FALSE to TRUE. Whenever this happens I want to insert the player's id and the date of the update. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION commitment_log()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        IF OLD.col_commit = TRUE THEN
            INSERT INTO commitment(player_id, committed_date)
            VALUES (OLD.player_id, now());
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER commitment_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE
ON player
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE commitment_log();
```

As of now, when I update a player's commitment in the player table to TRUE, nothing is updated in the commitment table.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain why checking your trigger condition in trigger `WHEN` section is better for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLD refers to the data that where before the update and NEW to the updated values.
As you only check the OLD.col_commit data, that is FALSE, you never will get a log entry.

so simply change the trigger to check for NEW.col_commit

Belayer is right, this should be an `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER` vecause, it will only be run when the update was commited, a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER` will run before the commit and could change the data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION commitment_log()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.col_commit = TRUE THEN
            INSERT INTO commitment(player_id, committed_date)
            VALUES (OLD.player_id, now());
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER commitment_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON player
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE commitment_log();
```

see [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XfpPah-n)

Of course, if you want only to capture the changes from FALSE to TRUE, you need also to check the OLD value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION commitment_log()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.col_commit = TRUE AND OLD.col_commit = FALSE THEN
            INSERT INTO commitment(player_id, committed_date)
            VALUES (OLD.player_id, now());
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER commitment_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON player
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE commitment_log();
```

Comment: Both answers below fulfill your requirements. However, there is another change you really need. This should be changed to an `after update` trigger. This is because another before update trigger could fire afterward and undo setting of `col_commit` column creating a data inconsistency. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html):   "multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name".  Lets see [this in action](https://dbfiddle.uk/WHwCDO4e).

Comment: i undated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `old.col_commit=TRUE` instead of `new.col_commit=TRUE and old.col_commit=FALSE` that you described.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION commitment_log()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO commitment(player_id, committed_date)
        VALUES (OLD.player_id, now());        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER commitment_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE
ON player
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.col_commit IS True AND old.col_commit IS False)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE commitment_log();
```

[Basic demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sUnVBjoz)

I didn't initially stress this, but specifying your condition in trigger [`WHEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) section as I suggest above is just better for performance. If you do it at the beginning of trigger body, it'll always fire on update, adding overhead, even if it's not needed.

```
explain analyze update player set col_commit=False;--90000 rows

Update on player p  (cost=0.00..13817.54 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=1910.569..1910.570 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on player p  (cost=0.00..13817.54 rows=983554 width=7) (actual time=1.729..52.606 rows=90000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.086 ms
Trigger commitment_trigger: time=240.780 calls=90000
Execution Time: 1910.603 ms
```

If you do it in `WHEN`, it'll do the check and abort without firing and incurring costs related to that. Note shorter execution time and no trigger calls compared to the earlier plan:

```
explain analyze update player set col_commit=False;--90000 rows

Update on player p  (cost=0.00..6908.77 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=1130.119..1130.120 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on player p  (cost=0.00..6908.77 rows=491777 width=7) (actual time=14.578..43.190 rows=90000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.057 ms
Execution Time: 1130.148 ms--(no trigger calls, shorter execution time)
```

See [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OWKX6zqw).